# How to Python Web Crawl (No tags, No div name, No class name)

Tags: python, web-crawler

I know need a name tag for web crawling. (ex: class='abcd')
But now the  I'm trying to have does not have this name.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiJ2s.png)

I want to extract **1** in (span)1(span) from the image value.
how to this?

always thank the users of **stackoverflow.**

Comment: CSS selectors can also be used to choose children based on known selectors of their parent, will your desired value always be under an svg with class ipl-icon? or always under some svg that is under span with class rating-other-user-rating?

Comment: You can access the class `ipl-icon ipl-star-icon` and then access the tag `span`

Comment: Please insert html code via [edit] using the snippet tool. Avoid pictures of html when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :has pseudo selector to specify span with sibling span having class .point-scale

```
soup.select_one('span:has(~ .point-scale)').text
```

That is a general sibling. You can also be more specific with adjacent sibling

```
soup.select_one('span:has(+ .point-scale)').text
```

Use `select` and list comprehension for multiple matches:

```
ratings = [item.text for item in soup.select('span:has(~ .point-scale)')]
```

---

Combinators (Quotes from Mozilla dev pages)

[Adjacent sibling combinator:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and
>   matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first
>   element, and both are children of the same parent element.

[General sibling combinator:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

> The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches
>   the second element only if it follows the first element (though not
>   necessarily immediately), and both are children of the same parent
>   element.

Comment: I solved the problem, but I was curious
I'll ask you one more question.
The (+)  is the above brother.
and Explain (~) about you
 'You can also be more specific with adjacent sibling'
but. I'm not of difference with (~,+) ... how do I use (~)?